# Unwrapping double to a string in java

Tags: java, string, double

In Java, for storing large numbers(10^80 to 10^100), we will be using `Double`. But `Double` will return in ae^x format where x is exponent value.Is there any way to unwrap it to a string.
Eg: `Double d = 1000000000;`

```
 Double.toString(d); --> output: 1.0E9.
```

Instead I want it as 1000000000

Comment: See java.text.DecimalFormat: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html

Comment: Do you have the option of using something else, like `BigInteger` if they're natural values or `BigDecimal` if they're fractional?  Beware that you may not necessarily get the results you hope for with doubles, as the binary representation is imperfect.

Comment: You should be aware that you'll lose precision on those numbers when they're stored as doubles; you only get 53 bits of precision, or about 16 decimal digits.

Answer (score 5):

Use a [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
double d = 1000000000;
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#");
System.out.println(df.format(d));
```

From the Javadocs:

> ```
> Integer:
>
>     MinimumInteger
>
>     #
>
>     # Integer
>
>     # , Integer
> ```